# What's the proper way to write this program?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing a program that allows your to enter four numbers & print out two pairs, if the input consists of two matching pairs. I know that arrays is the quicker way to perform this but I am not allowed to use them.

Here's my code so far:

```
new scan = new Scanner(System.in)
int n1 = input.nextInt();
int n2 = input.nextInt();
int n3 = input.nextInt();
int n4 = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Please enter 4 numbers: ");

if (n1 == n2 || n1 == n3 || n1 == n4 || n2 == n3 || n2 == n4 || n3 == n4){
    System.out.println("Two pairs"); 
} else { 
    System.out.println("Not two pairs");
}
```

I know it has to include if/else if/else statements but I'm just confused about how to write it after this part. I also have to include an error message if I were to input an invalid value (ex. a double, char).

Comment: Can you show an algorithm or code you tried to find pairs and print them? It's easier for us to help you in a way that will ultimately help you learn if we can see your code and attempt, and address exactly where the issue is.

Comment: if (n1 == n2 || n1 == n3 || n1 == n4 || n2 == n3 || n2 == n4 || n3 == n4) {
      System.out.println("Two pairs");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Not two pairs");

Comment: Your code currently detects one or more matching pairs. You'll need to add logic (likely using `&&` and parentheses for clarity) to detect only the cases where there are two matching pairs.

Comment: This line is definitely not right: `new scan = new Scanner(System.in)`. Maybe you mean: `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)` ? Also `System.out.print("Please enter 4 numbers: ")` should come before you call the first `input.nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently detects one or more matching pairs. You'll need to add logic (likely using && and parentheses for clarity) to detect only the cases where there are two matching pairs.

There are only three cases then that you need to check for:

- n1 == n2 and n3 == n4
- n1 == n3 and n2 == n4
- n1 == n4 and n2 == n3

Knowing this, and that `&&` means "and", can you now write this code?

---

Additionally, there are a few other issues in your code, that make it seem as if you haven't tested it yet. Testing code, even incomplete code, is a very important step in writing good code. The issues I saw were as follows:

- `new scan = new Scanner(System.in)` looks fishy. It should be `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)`.
- You're telling the user to input numbers AFTER the scanner calls. They won't see the prompt to put in four numbers until after they've input the four numbers.

Comment: @Skippy Simple. `if` there's a match, print that there is a match. `else` print a message stating there is no match.